# Android ImageButton - determine what resource is currently set

Tags: android, resources, imagebutton, drawable

Is there a way I can find what resource a particular ImageButton is set to, at any given time?

For eg: I have an ImageButton that I set to `R.drawable.btn_on` onCreate. Later, at some point, the ImageButton gets set to `R.drawable.btn_off`. I want to be able to check what resource the ImageButton is set to in my code.

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use `setTag()` and `getTag()` to associate and retrieve custom data for your `ImageView`.

Answer (score 3):

You could define your own class as a child of `ImageButton`, add a private int variable and set it when `setImageResource(int)` is called. Something like:

```
public class MyImageButton extends ImageButton {

    private int mImageResource = 0;

    @Override
    public void setImageResource (int resId) {
        mImageResource = resId;
        super.setImageResource(resId);
    }

    public int getImageResource() {
        return mImageResource;
    }
}
```

I didn't test it, but you get the idea - then you can call getImageResource() on your button, assuming it has been previously set with setImageResource().

Comment: That said, I agree with slup - if you want to test the state of your button, there are more logical ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to access the resource directly, but for what you try to achieve, wouldn't it suffice to just get the state?

```
    ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    int [] states = btn.getDrawableState();
    for (int i : states) {
        if (i == android.R.attr.state_pressed) {
            Log.v("btn", "Button in pressed state");
        }
    }
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#state_pressed

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#state_pressed) is incorrect. Here it states that `pickDropPoint.getDrawableState()[android.R.attr.state_pressed]` returns `true` or `false`, but instead it returns `1` or `0`, an `**int**`.

I had to do the following to get it working

```
            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/pickDropPoint"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:background="#EEeeeee4"
            android:contentDescription="pick or drop point"
            android:src="@drawable/pickupdrop" />
```

The drawable xml for pressed feel

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:src="@drawable/start32" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:src="@drawable/end32" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="3dp"
        android:topRightRadius="3dp" />

</selector>
```

In code, you dont need the for loop as suggested by @slup

```
whichPoint = (pickDropPoint.getDrawableState()[android.R.attr.state_pressed] > 1 ? PICKUP : DROP);
```