# Get ToggleButton drawable from selector

Tags: android

I have a ToggleButton that uses a selector to choose between 2 images (checked and unchecked).

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/img_piece1" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item     android:drawable="@drawable/img_piece2" /> <!-- default/unchecked -->
</selector>
```

Is there a way to retrieve the current drawable resource (checked/unchecked) of the toggle button in code? I tried using the ToggleButton.getBackground(), however this only seems to return the default Drawable always.

Comment: I did come across this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147299/android-imagebutton-determine-what-resource-is-currently-set) with some more searching, and am looking into using setTag() and getTag().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to do this and so am answering my own question. :)

Apparently the current drawable can be retrieved with ToggleButton.getBackground().**getCurrent()**

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

i was in same situation few days ago..
but made my way out by giving its TEXT ON ="." and TextOFF as "" ie blank...
that dot wont be seem on that image (probably) coz mine did not.
works well
 then check the text on toggle button.

Comment: Well, I am already using the ToggleButton.isChecked() to determine the current state and using that to specify the correct image. However I would like to get the current image without resorting to checking the state or checking some other attr if possible. As that "may" lead to a disconnect later between the image used by the selector (if I forget to update in either place).

Comment: Hey, found a better way to do this. Check my answer below for details.

Answer (score 0):

Though I haven't ever played with it, you may want to take a look at `getDrawableState()`. It may have what you're looking for.

Comment: I had a look but just can't seem to figure out how to use the returned int array[] values to get the Drawable. Dumping the values showed the following 3 values (for the toggle button in the checked state), [0]=0x101009d, [1]=0x101009e ,[2]=0x10100a0. Which according to R.attr are 'state_window_focused', 'state_enabled', 'state_checked'